# Using a server_name variable in an nginx proxy_pass config

Tags: nginx

I have two back-ends with different data that I want to test my UI code against, so I'm trying to configure Nginx to allow me to switch between them based on URL.

So for example, the local URL `https://ui.local.otherserver:80` would try my local files then proxy anything else to `https://otherserver:80`.

I'm trying to avoid having two `server` blocks as the config below is simplified and duplication is a pain.

The behaviour I'm seeing is that one of the back-ends works fine, and the other one gives me a 502 (Bad Gateway) error, but if I hard-code either server's name in the `proxy_pass` line it works as expected, i.e. successfully proxies to that specific server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
ssl             on;
ssl_certificate      /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.ui.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.ui.key;

server {
    listen          443;
    listen          80;
    server_name     ~^ui\.local\.(?<backend>.+)$;
    expires         -1;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/ui.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/ui.error.log;

    root /Users/richard/Projects/ui/trunk/;

    location ~ ^(.*)$ {
        try_files $1 @platform;
    }
    location @platform {
        proxy_pass https://$backend:$port;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything in the nginx error log?

Comment: In fact, you will have much more pain with overcomplicated ineffective config that you are trying to accomplish, instead of two simple server blocks. A web-server configuration is not a programming language, and should not be. So, why bother about duplication, then?

Comment: @mgorven yes! "no resolver defined to resolve..." this was a DNS issue, now fixed. Thanks for that. If you write up an answer I'll give you the credit

Comment: @VBart, as I mentioned, my real config is much larger than this and evolving, and I keep having to make every change twice. This has solved an actual real-world problem for me, so your argument about what a web server config should or shouldn't be seems a little academic. Happy to listen if you want to rephrase it in more pragmatic terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

502 is a Bad Gateway error, which means that nginx was unable to communicate with the backend. There should be a more detailed message in the nginx error log explaining what the communication error was. Have a look in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (or similar) to find the actual cause.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set explicit "resolver" directive in your server config or the location config for this to work. With use of variables in proxy_pass directive, NGINX needs to do a run time resolution. Here gethostbyname() cannot be used since its a blocking call. So NGINX expects an async resolver to be configured, otherwise it will give 502 bad gateway.